# How can I search commit message in BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket

How can I search the commit message in BitBucket? I can only search the codes but that doesn't help me. I want to find the **keyword** `HDMI` in the **commit title** for example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a search box for commits on the Bitbucket webpage, under *Commits*.

Comment: I guess it's gone now? Or our install lacks it.

Comment: I don't see it either.

Comment: You need to select `Show All` to display all the commit in different branches, then on the right hand side there should be a Find commits box.

Comment: It has move to "All Branches Graph"

Answer (score 14):

If you are using source tree its easy :-)

[image]

In the new versions:

[image]

Comment: Yep, I agree that third party software usually make life easier. However, in some company that has strict confidential rules might not allow employer to install any software by their own.

Comment: Wow, hidden at simple sight. A shortcut from the Edit menu would be nice for people like me (as it made more sense to search for commits in the History as a filter-style search.

Comment: And if I want to search multiple repos at once?

Answer (score 2):

If you also have the project locally, you can also search for the log via the console. Don't forget to do a git pull first, to be on the same level as remote.

`git log --oneline | grep PATTERN`

Answer (score 0):

To search specifically on the commits message you can use the aforementioned search box of the BitBucket page and use the operator 'keyword(string)' or 'grep(regex)'